# Get video src using JS and/or Xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, video, src

I am unable to to get the video src from ezgif site (it converts gif file into video) for example this [link](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4?url=https://media.tenor.com/images/191fae848ffdb9023b81352762b57c68/tenor.gif).
I have tried

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].src;
console.log(a);
```

but it ends in **Cannot read property 'src' of undefined**

What I want is to open that src in same tab or in new tab.

And how can I select a src using Xpath method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src attribute isn't on the video tag, it's on the source tag inside it.

`document.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src` or `document.querySelectorAll("video source")[0].src` would work.

Comment: Are you certain that you're running this code *after* the video element is inserted into the page?  Does `document.getElementsByTagName("source")` return anything on its own?

Comment: Yes. It runs after the video inserted (page loaded). It returns "Cannot read property 'src' of undefined"

Comment: The video is not inserted on page load, it's inserted after the user clicks the "Convert gif to mp4" button... so if you're running on document load there's no video element yet.   To confirm: when you run `document.getElementsByTagName("source")` do you get an empty HTMLCollection?

Comment: No. I am testing it on the convert page. Where video has appeared after clicking the button.

Comment: That's where I'm testing too.  When you load that convert page, there is no video on it.  The video is inserted via an ajax call only after the user clicks the "convert" button.  Third time: what happens when you run `document.getElementsByTagName("source") `?  If you get an empty collection, that means there is no video yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188926/discussion-between-sarmadk-and-daniel-beck).